# Kendo UI ASP.NET MVC ListView fails when trying to add or edit items

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, listview, razor, kendo-ui

I'm struggling to set up a ListView which allows me to add new records and to update existing ones. Loading the items for the list works like a charm. Also showing the only relevant information `Id` and `Line` works perfectly.

Two problems:
 1. Adding a new item to the list: I see the ugly form which allows to set the value for `Id` and `Line`. But there is no way for me to save it.
 2. Updating an existing item: I see the ugly form which allows to set the value for `Id` and `Line`. But the fields are empty. They should be pre-filled with whatever has been shown before. Again, there is no way for me to save it.

My code looks pretty similar to what is provided in Telerik's Examples Project. Unfortunately, I fail to find the minor difference...

The extremely stripped code of the ListView (still not working as intended):

```
@using System.Collections
@using TestcaseRepositoryAPI.Model.Domain;

@model TemplateGeneratorItem

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "VORLAGE";
    ViewBag.SubTitle = "erstellen";
    ViewBag.ShowMenu = true;
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_LayoutMetro.cshtml";
}

@Html.Partial("_MetroPageHeader")

<div class="demo-section">
    <a class="k-button k-button-icontext k-add-button" href="#"><span class="k-icon k-add"></span>Add new record</a>
</div>

<div class="demo-section k-header">
    @(Html.Kendo().ListView<TemplateGeneratorItem.Record>(Model.Records)
        .Name("RecordsList")
        .ClientTemplateId("recordLinesTemplate")
        .DataSource(d => d
            .Events(e => e.RequestStart("requestStart").RequestEnd("requestEnd"))
            .Create("RecordLineCreate", "Metro")
            .Read("RecordLinesRead", "Metro")
            .Update("RecordLineUpdate", "Metro")
            .Destroy("RecordLineDelete", "Metro")
            .Model(m => m.Id(o => o.Line))
        )
        .Editable()
        //.Events(e => e.Remove("removeRecord"))
        .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "border:none;" })
        .TagName("div")
    )
</div>

<script type="text/x-kendo-tmpl" id="recordLinesTemplate">
    <div class="k-widget" style="margin:10px auto 10px auto;">
        <fieldset>
            <legend>Zeile #=Line#</legend>

            <div class="edit-buttons">
                <a class="k-button k-button-icontext k-edit-button" href="\\#"><span class="k-icon k-edit"></span></a>
                <a class="k-button k-button-icontext k-delete-button" href="\\#"><span class="k-icon k-delete"></span></a>
            </div>

            <dl>
                <dt>ID</dt>
                <dd>#:Id#</dd>
            </dl>
        </fieldset>
    </div>
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function requestStart(e) {
        console.log("requestStart(e)", e);
    }

    function requestEnd(e) {
        console.log("requestEnd(e)", e);
        console.log("e.type", e.type);
        if (e.response) {
            console.log("e.response", e.response);
        }
    }

    function getRecList() {
        return $("#RecordsList").data("kendoListView");
    }

    $(".k-add-button").click(function (e) {
        getRecList().add();
        e.preventDefault();
    });
</script>
```

The snippet of the controller which returns the data:

```
public JsonResult RecordLinesRead([DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest request)
{
    List<TemplateGeneratorItem.Record> records = GetTemplateGeneratorItemFromSession().Records;
    int line = 1;
    foreach (TemplateGeneratorItem.Record record in records)
    {
        record.Line = line++;
    }

    return Json(records.ToTreeDataSourceResult(request), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

And finally the classes of the model:

```
namespace TestcaseRepositoryAPI.Model.Domain
{
    [DataContract]
    public class TemplateGeneratorItem
    {
        [DataMember]
        public List<Record> Records { get; set; }

        public class Record
        {
            [DataMember]
            //[ScaffoldColumn(false)]
            public int Line { get; set; }

            [DataMember]
            public string Id { get; set; }

            [DataMember]
            [ScaffoldColumn(false)]
            public List<RecordField> Fields { get; set; }

            public Record() { }

            public Record(Record record)
            {
                Line = record.Line;
                Id = record.Id;
                Fields = record.Fields;
            }
        }

        public class RecordField
        {
            [DataMember]
            public string Name { get; set; }

            ...
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it. The Telerik support asked the right questions.

The problem is quite simple: There is no editor template specified! There are (at least?) two ways to resolve this issue:
 1. Specify the name of the editor template (e.g. `.Editable(e => e.Editable(true).TemplateName("TemplateGeneratorRecord"))`) and create the TemplateGeneratorRecord.cshtml in the EditorTemplates folder.
 2. Or let some magic happen by creating an editor template in the EditorTemplates folder called Record.cshtml. That's the solution used in Telerik's examples.

I've chosen the first option. Now it is working as expected.